# How to preserve original DOM structure when setting inner HTML to invalid HTML

Tags: javascript, html, semantics

I am setting `innerHTML` of a DOM element to  a string which contains button within a button:

```
document.body.innerHTML="<div>test0<button>test1<button>test2</button></button></div>"
```

When HTML is rendered, Chrome is taking out button outside of the button:
[image: ht]

Is  there  anything I can do to preserve the nesting as is after applying innerHTML?
Unfortunately, I can't change the fact that they are nested (external component generates this structure).

Test jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/4r5mcn67/

Comment: You can not control how browser handles invalid markup. All you can do is be sure to use valid markup to start with. Why would you ever nest a button inside another one?

Comment: What is the broader problem you want to solve? As @charlietfl mentioned it doesn't make sense to nest buttons anyway.

Comment: What's the expected result? Button inside button?!

Answer (score 0):

***Despite the fact that nested button is not valid HTML*** **and that your external component should be fixed first**.

This might be actually possible to test if the browser will preserve your component's HTML structure or not, before editing the DOM of your page.

**This is very limited:**

- Browsers often "fix" tags (lowercase, auto closing, whitespaces, ...) despite the fact that your HTML code is valid.
- This will slow down your performance, since your browser will have to do the work twice when it's valid.

But you can "sort of verify" how the browser is constructing your DOM element, by creating this element and then compare its rendered inner HTML with the original HTML.

```js
let invalidHtml = "<div>test0<button>test1<button>test2</button></button></div>"; // Invalid HTML with nested button's tags.

let validHtml = "<div>test0<button>test1</button><button>test2</button></div>"; // Valid HTML.

let validHtml2 = "<div>test0</DIV>"; // Valid HTML, but will be evaluated as "Invalid".

/**
 * Check if an HTML code structure is preserved by the browser.
 */
function isValidHtml(innerHtml) {
  let testElement = document.createElement('div');
  testElement.innerHTML = innerHtml;

  return testElement.innerHTML === innerHtml; // Strict comparison (very limited application).
}

console.info(isValidHtml(invalidHtml)); // return false.
console.info(isValidHtml(validHtml));   // return true.
console.info(isValidHtml(validHtml2));  // return false.
```

**Overall it will be more judicious to see why this external component is generating invalid HTML structure.**